# StaggeredGridLayout manager with 2 columns and fixed image height

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing recycler listview with 2 columns using StaggeredGridLayoutManager.
And I am getting grids with all different heights.
But I want grids populating with only two specific height dimensions.
Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you tried using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265986/dynamically-setting-a-fixed-height-for-a-staggered-grid-view.

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to get the desired result